# How to enable Depth Buffer per node on cocos2dx v3

Tags: opengl, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, depth-buffer

I have a scene that needs depth buffering. If I call

```
Director::getInstance()->setDepthTest(true);
```

just before creating my scene and my camera everything works correctly. But if I call it in a `CustomCommand` callback It doesn't do anything.

I can't have it enabled for the whole scene, since it breaks labels and other common UI items, so I have to enable depth test only on some nodes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to call `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` and `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` in your `CustomCommand` callback.

Comment: Hey, i've tried that with no luck